# Caching calls to an external API in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, caching

The rails app (4) calls an external API using HTTParty. The API is read only. Caching is required as the data does not change often (24h) and the API allow only a limited number of calls per hour.

I guess I need some kind of hash based cache where I will use "params/sent/to/the/api" as key.
Rails tools for caching seems only to be for pages,fragments or SQL.

What should I do to cache calls to an external API?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It'll be something like this.  Basically, the Rails.cache.fetch call will wrap your API call.  It won't hit the API unless the cache has expired.

```
class Results

  def get(url, params)
    Rails.cache.fetch([url, params], :expires => 1.hour) do
      HTTParty.get('url/to/api')
    end
  end

end
```

Be sure you have a cache set in your environment. Memcache works great for this sort of thing.

Comment: Isn't it over the top to install a server for a cache that will have, at most, 5000 entries?

Comment: It's pretty easy to have memcache running, but to keep it simple, you can cache a few different ways - file server may be what you want.  I haven't worked very much with file caches, not sure how expires works there.

Comment: @Syl As Swards points out, a separate cache server is not needed, but even if one does elect to use memcached, it's not complex.  It's a very simple service to install and run.